# are there any brands of laptops that are not compatable with Ubuntu?

Tags: laptop

I know we used to have lists of laptops that were able to be used for Ubuntu, and that HP and Lenova have supplied some Linux computers. However, the last HP computer I bought, and ENVY, did not allow me to load Ubuntu on it. So, since my old trusty Pavilion has now broken a hinge, I am looking for a new computer but there have been no updated lists that I know of. So, who knows which of the new laptops is good for Ubuntu and which ones to avoid? Since AMD chips sometimes have trouble, is there a good choice for the intel chips? Or does it matter? Has the newest versions of Ubuntu fixed the problems of the Microsoft lock for the computers?

Comment: We are not a hardware related site ;) It is better to google for a specific notebook and check a hardware compatibility list like http://linuxhardware.net/linuxhardware/notes/ " However, the last HP computer I bought, and ENVY, did not allow me to load Ubuntu on it" Ubuntu works on an ENVY with some extra handling: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2123975&p=12570313#post12570313

Comment: @Adam Albanowicz: if you've heard that Secure Boot is a system that locks users to Windows, you have been misinformed. In fact, Ubuntu was the first operating system that supported Secure Boot, even before Windows. All supported versions of Ubuntu supports it out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are a lot of questions here and I will try to answer most of them. Here I will be speaking mostly from experience with Ubuntu over the last couple of years.

## Officially supported Ubuntu laptops

Canonical keeps a list of laptops and desktops that have been thoroughly tested. If support is the most important thing to you, find something on this list. Personally, I think the list is a bit restricted. I have used a ton of hardware that isn't certified by Canonical and most of it has worked with no problems at all. That being said, I have wasted hundreds of dollars with hardware that I thought would work, and it didn't.

There isn't a specific manufacturer who has good or bad support for Linux, it all depends on the machine. You might notice that most certified machines are made by Dell and HP, but you could find great support from any manufacturer.

- http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/desktop/

Surprisingly I have found Amazon.com a very helpful source of information. You can look at the reviews for a lot of popular products and easily find out if it has Linux support. You will know quickly if something has poor Linux support by looking at the user reviews. If you see a lot of Linux users complaining about bad support, its probably not worth your time.

Quick side note: [System76](https://system76.com/) makes great (and expensive) Linux laptops.

## Processor Support

This is pretty easy to answer, and I think a lot of people will agree with me on this one: Ubuntu can run equally well on AMD and Intel. A lot of people stick with AMD for building gaming machines because they are cheap, but Intel chips last longer and run cooler. If you're on a tight budget, go with AMD, but if you are willing to spend more money, go with Intel.

## "Microsoft lock"

I'm not sure what you're referring to here, but here are a couple things off of the top of my head:

- **Safe Boot**

  - This is just one of those things that Microsoft has enabled by default that doesn't add that much security anyway. It can be disabled in the BIOS pretty easily on most installs.
- **UFEI**

  - At first, Ubuntu had some trouble with installing in UFEI mode especially while dual booting windows and Ubuntu. The installer has gotten much better and this shouldn't be an issue anymore.
- **Manufacturer Locked BIOS**

  - There isn't much you can do here, fortunately this is not very common. P.S. users hate this 'feature' (*cough cough* Android).

### Summary

Google is your friend. You can find information about Linux support for hardware on many different Linux forums. When in doubt, go with hardware that is certified by Canonical.

Answer (score 0):

### Simple answer: NO

---

*Some newer models of laptop may have features that are yet supported. Moreover, some hardware features may be from an electronics manufacturer who does not (and will not) release documentation or source code to allow the device to work properly with open source and/or Linux.*

*However, that is not specific or characteristic of any particular **brand** of laptop.*